# Hiding div - selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a big problem with my script for Greasemonkey. I'm using this code to hide unnecessary divs me on the web:

```
$("div[data-title='Mair Mask']").hide()
```

It works perfectly for the majority of these - for example:

```
$("div[data-title='Googly Gazer']").hide()
$("div[data-title='Medic&apos;s Mountain Cap']").hide()
```

Unfortunately - this code does not work with several divs. It is very wird because I copied the data-title, and pasted it very carefully to the code. Despite this - I am not able to hide divs such as, for example:

```
 Madame Dixie
 Brain Bucket
 Surgeon&apos;s Side Satchel
```

Of course I've tried this:

```
 $("div[data-title='Madame Dixie']").hide()
 $("div[data-title='Brain Bucket']").hide()
 $("div[data-title='Surgeon;s Side Satchel']").hide()
```

The situation is very strange, because the individual divs do not differ among themselves, and makes me wonder why the code works with most, but not all.

I've tried to insert the   instead of spacebar in the names of those divs....

```
  $("div[data-title='Madame&nbsp;Dixie']").hide()
```

but it's useless.

You are my last hope. The following link to the source page (I do not give a link because it requires registration) - https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qumlg4eh1ki41s/sourcecode.txt?dl=0

Comment: try `$("div[data-title='Medic\'s Mountain Cap']").hide()`. This escapes the apostrophe.

Comment: But this code works fine. It's not the fault of the apostrophe, most broken selectors did not contain (Madame Dixie, Brain Bucket)

Comment: And no ideas why it's dont work? Maybe the reason is in the page code?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6h1b9t6/) and it works. Maybe there's some error in the HTML

```
<div data-title="Madame Dixie"></div>

$("div[data-title='Madame Dixie']").hide()

div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}
```

Comment: This code works for sure because I use it for a long time. I wonder, however, these exceptions which he does not want to hide. As for the errors in the HTML - of course it is very possible, but at first glance the structure of all divs (those that hide the code, and those that do not) it looks identical. I added the source page at the end of my post.

Comment: I was talking about "Madame Dixie", a string that you said it's not working with and it did.

Comment: Yeah, but not on website. Still, thanks for the help